# Scoped Pointer in Boost : What does mean a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, raw-pointer

I read in article about **Smart Pointers** in Boost that :

> "**scoped_ptr** is good for **raw pointers**, while **scoped_array** is useful for **dynamic arrays**."

But I didn't get what they mean by "Raw pointers", so neither the sentence.

Could anyone of you explain to me this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Their wording is unfortunate. By "raw" pointers, people usually mean the primitive pointer types, regardless of what they point to. What they mean is:

scoped_ptr is good for pointers to single objects, while scoped_array is useful for dynamic arrays

Answer (score 1):

Raw pointer is a pointer introduced by language syntax with `*`:

```
int* ptr;
```

This is a normal POD ("raw" numeric address in memory) variable, so it destructs trivially. What's important and annoying about raw pointers is:

```
int* ptr = new int(42);
```

because of the fact that destruction of `ptr` is a no-op, `delete` won't be called and you have to do it manually. Smart pointers wrap around raw pointers and destroy objects pointed to (when necessary to do so).

C++11 introduced smart pointers into the standard library in forms of `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. You should use those instead of boost ones when targetting C++11.

The mention of arrays comes from the fact that we can represent an array as a pointer to the first element and some notion of size. For example, `char*` is a pointer to the first character in the array, and we know that it ends at `'\0'`. Dynamic allocations of such arrays are done by `new[]` operator (and destructions by `delete[]`); smart pointers from standard library can handle those types too, but in general use of `std::vector` is advised instead.